# Variable amount of fields in Spring form

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp

I need to put variable amount of the same type of fields in the form. Let's say I have a command object

```
public class Person
  String name;
  String surname;

// getters and setters
```

and a jsp

```
<form:form command="personCommand">
  <form:input path="name"/>
  <form:input path="surname"/>
</form:form>
```

that's the standard way when I have a static number of fields. But what if I have something like

```
<form:form command="personCommand">
  <c:forEach items="${persons}">
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <form:input path="surname"/>
  </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

(which is of course incorrect) where the number of persons is unknown in advance? Is there some way in Spring to bind the fields in an array or a list maybe? Or some kind of workaround (currently I am concatenating the fields with javascript and separating them programatically which is Ugly).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class(PersonWrapper) and include the List of persons as a variable in that class.
Then in JSP, you can use the following syntax

```
<c:forEach items="${personWrapper.persons}" varStatus="i">
  <form:input path="persons[${i.index}].name"/>
  <form:input path="persons[${i.index}].surname"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Then in the controller, you can get the values in List of persons

Comment: What if the amount of person records would change in the interface by using javascript to add additional inputs (with the correct path/index)? How can spring bind these "new" persons?